# cross browser href inside href?

Tags: html, css

**i have css look like below**

```
ul.sometclass li a {

display:inline-block;
}
```

**my html look like**

```
<ul class="someclass">
<li>
  <a href="outertest.html">outer test 

         <div style="display:inline; float:left;overflow: hidden;">
                   <a href="innertest.html"><div style="display:inline; float:left;">inner test</a>
                   <a href="innertest.html"><div style="display:inline; float:left;">inner test</a>
        </div>
   </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

1.for cross browser support, is it ok to use href inside href ?
2. is my **ul.someclass li a** affect  inner **a_href** ?  seem to me , it affect and on firefox, even though i put as inline, it render as block . on ie is ok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> for cross browser support, is it ok to use href inside href ?

No, definitely not. Nested `<a>` elements are invalid and begging for trouble.

You should fix this first before trying to correct any other problems possibly connected with this.

Comment: a minor semantic suggestion: I don't think it's 'begging' for trouble, as such: it's more *going out and actively demanding, seeking and pursuing trouble...* =b

Answer (score 3):

You should not be nesting block level elements within inline elements (i.e. div nested in an a href element)

Answer (score 0):

In order to have nested a please do the following changes ....

You have to wrap the nested a inside a `object` tag.

```
<ul class="someclass">
<li>
  <a href="outertest.html">outer test 

         <div style="display:inline; float:left;overflow: hidden;">
                   <object><a href="innertest.html"><div style="display:inline; float:left;">inner test</a></object>
                   <object><a href="innertest.html"><div style="display:inline; float:left;">inner test</a></object>
        </div>
   </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to achieve the same effect, you could do something like:

```
<div class="outer">
   <a ... /a>
</div>
<a class="floatLink" ... /a>
```

Then, with some clever positioning and z-indexing, you can make the float link appear inside the outer a tag whilst retaining cross browser support.